# Screen densities and images dimensions

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, screen-resolution, android-resolution

Hi Android developers,

I want to know how to choose the dimensions of drawables; for example, I have an image that I want to insert in my app, what size (pixel) the image should be to be inserted inside xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, and ldpi ?

I've analyzed many android apps on GitHub, they use random image sizes (pixel) for different densities.

Comment: Those declarations have been deprecated for quite a while.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts which is a bit obtuse (as much android API documentation is) for the "new" method.

Comment: @alzee which still does not answer the question

Comment: Which is why it's posted as a comment and not an answer, @Code-Apprentice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the **3:4:6:8:12:16 scaling ratio** between the six generalized densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screens, all the different sizes should be:
>
> - 36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
> - 48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
> - 72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
> - 96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
> - 144x144 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
> - 192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources

Comment: Clear and understandable. one more question: It's up to me to choose the initial size (in this case 48x48)  for mdpi ?

Comment: @ILYAS_Kerbal for icons, material design specifies 48x48 for the base dimensions. For other assets, you have more flexibility. See https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android). It contains all information necessary to decide which units to use. TL;DR is: never use absolute values in pixels, instead, use dp units for views (including images), and sp for text.

Supporting multiple devices is covered [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Also check the [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html) to learn the commonly used dimensions for icons, margins, etc

Comment: Thank you, the question is about drawable sizes not units.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use Android Asset Studio. It will generate all the required resolution of images for respective screen densities

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/